# Resetting Browser Zoom on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, zooming

I have a situation where I have two web pages. The user will be initially viewing page A at 100% percent zoom. They will then click a link to proceed to page B. They will zoom in/out of page B accordingly and then return to page A. The problem is page A will still be zoomed to the level that page B was left at. Is there any way to perhaps reset the browser zoom to 100% each time a new page loads. This is not a public website but rather a specific solution for my job where there will be only a specific number of users where this specific functionality has been requested. Also it doesn't have to be implemented this exact way as long as the user is able to view the page the way it was when they left it. I am open to any solution as long as this functionality is achieved in a reasonable manner. It seems to me that using JavaScript to change browser zoom is bad practice and also not really possible.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Why will they be zooming on page B? Is there another zoom functionality that you could provide that doesn't change the browser zoom? Think more like how maps do it.

Comment: @theoutlander Hi yes they will be zooming in and/or out of page B. I thought of providing a zoom functionality that allows the user to zoom using say CSS and JavaScript which I could reset when they go back all without changing the browser's zoom